# How do you tell the number of consumed map page views in google maps for your site?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-analytics, pageviews

**Question**: How do you tell the number of consumed map page views in google maps for your site? Is this information available in Google Analytics explicitly?

**Business background to my problem**: According to an email from google, our site is using more than 25,000 map page views per day. If correct, this would mean that we have to start paying for google maps. However, according to our metrics we are using far less than the allowed number of maps (page views, API downloads). Google analytics corroborates this, it says that our map pages are downloaded considerably less than 25,000 times per day.

This is a real problem for us - we have no idea of how many map page views Google thinks that we are using...

**Technical background:** The site I am working on is using google maps API v3, javascript version. Client side geocoding. We are loading the Google maps API only from pages that should have maps on them.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the google console dashboard to check the number of pages.

Also are you sure to have protected google maps for your domain only ? If not then maybe someone else is using your key !!

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply - I will try the google console dashboard! Could you give me a pointer to how to protect the key?

Comment: Welcome @user2660649 the option to allow a key for a particular domain is in the console itself. Feel free to upvote if the answer was helpful :)

Comment: Check in API access @user2660649 . Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your help woofmeow. Unfortunately I cannot upvote your answers since I don't yet have enough reputation.